# QuickBlox : Push notification settings

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, quickblox

Is it possible to change QuickBlox push notification template runtime?

[image]

Is it possible to send a message, having `save_to_history` enabled (true) and would not come as a push notification (even if push enabled).

Comment: No, it's not possible for now

Comment: How to manage custom template in alert

Comment: I am not sure about it as I don't have used it recently. You can ask a separate question for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is possible to modify the push notification template starting from the plan "Advanced". You can check full comparison of the plans [here](https://quickblox.com/plans/)